# Circular error on Apollo Client when trying to refetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollostack, react-apollo, apollo-client

My `App` component has a `reload` button. Clicking `reload` should essentially perform refetch by re-triggering the graphql query.

The way I am currently performing the reload is by using Apollos's refetch function when the user click `reload`. However, the following error occurs when I click reload:

[image]

Here is my graphql HOC code:

```
const mapApiToProps = graphql(ASSETS_QUERY, {
  props: ({ ownProps, data }) => {
    return {
      assets: data.assets,
      isLoading: data.loading,
      handleReload: data.refetch // Doesn't currently work
    }
  }
});
```

Here is my query:

```
export const ASSETS_QUERY = gql`
  query getUserAssets {
    assets {
      body
      id
    }
  }`
```

Here is my component code:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {handleReload, isLoading, assets} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReloadBtn handleReload={handleReload} isLoading={isLoading} />
        <AssetList assets={assets} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And finally, my connect:

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
  mapApiToProps
)(App);
```

Any insight into why the error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

```
return {
  assets: data.assets,
  isLoading: data.loading,
  handleReload: () => { data.refetch() }
}
```

Comment: Please explain yoir answers.

Comment: How is this different from what OP had? You added a lambda, but the method was being invoked anyway.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and for some reason passing () => refetch() instead of refetch to the onPress of the Button fixed the problem for me. So

```
<Button onPress={() => refetch()} title="some button"/>
```

instead of

```
<Button onPress={refetch} title="some button"/>
```